# References to study Weak and Strong Topologies and aproximations on function spaces of manifolds

Tags: reference-request, smooth-manifolds

I´m studing weak and strong topologies and aproximations on the function space  $C^{\infty}(M,N)$  of two manifolds $M$ and $N$.  I´m using the book  Differential Topology of Morris Hirsch but it is a very hard book for someone with no experience on topology of functions spaces. Can someone tell me a book where this subject is exposed  in a more accesible form?

Comment: I was about to ask the exact same question now. Hirsch's book drew me in with its table of contents but it turns out his proof style is very crude. At one point instead of defining partitions of unity subordinate to covers he maps the different charts to balls of different sizes in $\marhbb{R}^n$ and then uses a cut off function on the balls. VERY confusing! Anyway if anyone has a different source for the same material that appears in -Hirsch I could really use the recommendation.